# Difference between "other" and "another"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Why in this sentence "**Other**" is used?

"I find this shop very expensive. Next time I'll try **other** shop."

And in this other, **another** is used

"I'm not happy with this product.  Next time I'll buy **another** brand."

Is possible use other or another in both sentences?

Comment: you can try other shops, or another shop, or *the* other shop. But not other shop.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

> I'll try **other** shop.

Correct possible sentences are:

> I'll try **another** shop. (Any other shop.)
>
> I'll try **the other** shop. (When there is specifically one alternative.)
>
> I'll try **other shops**. (When there are multiple alternatives to choose from.)

Comment: You should explain what the differences between "other" and "another" are, since that seems to be OP's question.